# How do I delete a branch in sourcetree which has been deleted at source

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to delete a branch in Sourcetree which has been deleted on the source. I tried to use the delete branch with Force delete but got the following error message

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false
> --no-optional-locks branch -D feature/PC-776_Scribante_Monthly_Journals_by_Branch error: Cannot
> delete branch 'feature/PC-776_Scribante_Monthly_Journals_by_Branch'
> checked out at 'D:/sourcegit' Completed with errors, see above.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because I was in the branch to be deleted. Make sure you are in a different branch to the one you are trying to delete